# Implementing SendActionToNative in JS

Tags: javascript, java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have extended `CordovaActivity`, and implemented  `WLInitWebFrameworkListener` plus `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` in native code

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback{
```

1. Inside this class I have implemented

   ```
   @Override
   public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult arg0) {
   // if a device is connected launch application
   if(mConnectedGATT.connect()){
       WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(new ErosReceiver());
       super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());

       }
   else{Log.i(TAG, "Could not connect");}
   }
   ```
2. I have added the following to main.js in a function

   ```
   WL.App.SendActionToNative ("ReqSlaveList", data);
   ```
3. I have created another class `MyReceiver`

   ```
   public class MyReceiver implements WLActionReceiver {
   ```
4. Implemented

   ```
   public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data)
   ```

Now it seems like the `OnActionReceived` never gets called.

Comment: And if you remove `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback`, does it work? I suggest that you will start *small*. That is, make an "empty" implementation that only returns "hello". That way you know you have it working and you start extending it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to create a new class that implements `onInitWebFrameworkComplete`. You need to *append* your code to the **existing** application main class that already does this (and which MobileFirst Platform relies on).

You can find this application main class in your application's **native** folder in MobileFirst Studio. That is where you should declare your `ActionReceiver`. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/#action-receiver

Comment: Hi Idan Thanks for a prompt response. I have overriden the onInitWebFrameworkComplete because i needed to launch the mobilefirst app once a button is clicked on the native app. Previously my MainActivity was: `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` but there was no instance of WL found in onCreate() function so i implemented WLInitWebFrameworkListener and created an instance of WL and onClick initialized it, and onInitWebFrameworkComplete I am calling to load the mainhtmlfilepath

Comment: alternately, If I implement the existing application main class, how do i use that class's `super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());` in my native Mainactivity class when button onclick is done?

Comment: I now notice some warnings `W/System.err(28366):  at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)'` and `W/GCMHelperClient(28366): GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:139 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null`