# SendActionToNative Gives error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am sending an action and a JSON object to native code in mobilefirst. After resolving lots of [other][Implementing SendActionToNative in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301896/implementing-sendactiontonative-in-js/38302520#38302520) errors, now it says:

> E/NONE(31238): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object
>   Object] has no method 'SendActionToNative' at (compiled_code):105

My Javascript code goes here:

```
function getSlavesList(){
  alert("about to send action");
var data = {cmd:"1", msgid:"1"};
WL.App.SendActionToNative ("ReqSlaveList", data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct API method is `WL.App.sendActionToNative` - you're using a capital "S" instead of a lower-case "s": https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html